# Me sale error 500 en hosting, pero en localhost no

Tags: php, hosting, localhost

Tengo este sistema corriendo a la perfección en localhost pero al subirlo en hosting me manda error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el hosting me manda ese error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es por que me sale ese error por favor una ayudita

ajax/articulo.php

Comment: Revisa el log de errores en tu hosting

Comment: Por favor sigue la recomendación dada, de otro modo sin conocer el error exacto poco podemos hacer